# Widget becomes a different widget from another app

Tags: android, android-widget

I may be doing something stupid, but I have an interesting problem with my app widget. Every now and then, often after being added to the homescreen, it transforms into a widget from another app. This widget is always the same on a specific phone, but differs between phones. After a few seconds, the widget then returns back to how it should look. Although for me this isn't an issue as it is only a temporary problem, I have emails from users who say the widget is permanently stuck in another form.

Below are any files which could be relevant:

- [The widget provider](https://github.com/okey666/BBC-News-Reader/blob/master/src/com/digitallizard/bbcnewsreader/widget/ReaderWidget.java)
- [The widget configuration activity](https://github.com/okey666/BBC-News-Reader/blob/master/src/com/digitallizard/bbcnewsreader/widget/WidgetConfigActivity.java)
- [The widget xml layout](https://github.com/okey666/BBC-News-Reader/blob/master/res/layout/widget.xml)
- [Xml layout item](https://github.com/okey666/BBC-News-Reader/blob/master/res/layout/widget_item.xml)
- [Manifest](https://github.com/okey666/BBC-News-Reader/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml)

I'm sorry to attach so many but I really don't know where to start. I am hoping that to someone more familiar with the api the problem will be immediately apparent. I also apologize for any poor code as this is my first ever serious project and is just a hobby alongside schoolwork.

Comment: How about including your AndroidManifest.xml? My first suspicion would be something wrong with your package name or intent registration or something.

Comment: Additional to that: Stock, some vendor ROM or a custom one?

Comment: And by stock i mean vanilla android. Stupid me.

Comment: I have added the manifest. The problem occurs on a stock emulator and on both HTC sense and cyanogen on my phone. I can't speak for others.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue in my widget as you described and searched a lot for a solution and couldn't find any. What I ended up doing is some kind of workaround that seems to work fine in my case. What i did is the following, instead of updating the widgets directly from the onUpdate() method, I started a service that handled the update then killed itself. This solved it on the emulator and on a device that had the widget stuck during update.
Here's a sample code:

The AppWidgetProvider:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, WidgetService.class));
}
```

The Service:

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    started(intent);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    started(intent);
    return START_STICKY;
}


private void started(Intent intent) {
    //update here the widgets
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    updateWidgets(context);
    stopSelf();//killing the service
}

private void updateWidgets(Context context) {
    AppWidgetManager appmanager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    ComponentName cmpName = new ComponentName(context, widgetClass);
    int[] widgetIds = appmanager.getAppWidgetIds(cmpName);
    RemoteViews rView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), layoutId);
    for (int wid : widgetIds) {
        //all updates here
        rView.setTextViewText(tvId, desc);
        appmanager.updateAppWidget(wid, rView);
    }
}
```

Note sure why this workaround solves the issue, but the good thing is that it does
Hope this helps